# How do I make chromedriver suppress errors and warnings?

Tags: ruby, rspec, selenium-chromedriver, watir-webdriver

When using chromedriver 2.29 and watir-webdriver to drive a chrome browser on Windows 7 during automated tests or using IRB(interactive ruby shell) I constantly see errors and warnings written to standard output while the browser is in use.

Errors like this:
`ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(690)] eglInitialize D3D11 failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type`

This makes it difficult to use IRB because of the error text constantly getting in the way.  It also makes test output in rspec really problematic and hard to read because of all the NOISY ERRORS/WARNINGS.

How can all these errors be silenced?  I've tried to load up the browser with the --silent option that chromedriver has and this hasn't stopped the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to latest:
Chrome: Version 60.0.3112.78 (Official Build) (64-bit) 
AND chromedriver: version 2.30
No longer seeing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you want to ignore these errors you can use exceptions to ignore all the errors, you can read about how to do this here if you don't already know: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_exceptions.htm

If you want to keep the errors but make less clutter I would either write the errors to an error log file or write the text to an output log file.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't appear to help.  I tried wrapping the code that creates the browser object in a begin/end block and rescue any exception that should happen but no exception is seemingly thrown.  

These, I believe, are all chrome error/warnings being written into IRB output.  I have also tried to start irb with `--simple-prompt --noecho` but the errors still flood the command line.  

Do you have a working example of your solution or example code that I could try?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any example code, I personally haven't seen this problem before, my best suggestion if exceptions did not work is to send what you are sending to irb to a text file so you can read without the errors going to standard output. If you need input and can't send to a file, you could try changing the color of the output text you are trying to see to make it more visible and obvious, I'm sorry I don't have the exact answer, but I hope you can figure it out.

Comment: NP, thanks Jake.  Today I noticed that the issue is no longer happening using the latest chrome Version 60.0.3112.78 (Official Build) (64-bit) AND chromedriver 2.30.  I'm very happy and hope the issue never returns.

Comment: Glad to hear it was a simple fix, fingers crossed it wont happen again lol!